# Viewing the contents of tables in schema.rb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schema, database-schema, schema.rb

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but in my schema.rb I have several tables like

```
  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",            :null => false
    t.string   "message",            :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
  end
```

Is it possible to view the contents of each table i.e view each message and associated user id, message content, time created at, linked image, etc?

Thanks

Comment: you need to use your DB console for that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [database schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) represents the structure of the database, not the content of it.

If you want to access the content in your database, you would query it to do so. You can do that via command line clients (running `$ rails dbconsole` will try to open one for the configured database) or graphical tools like Sequel Pro (for MySQL on Mac OS X).

You can also get this through your Rails application by running `$ rails console` and then using the methods available through ActiveRecord (e.g. `Post.all` or `User.where(:name => 'Billy').limit(5)`).

Comment: Yes, I have sequel pro but how exactly do I access the content of the database from it? Thanks

Comment: Uh, that's how you use it. That's most of what it does. I'm confused. http://www.sequelpro.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gem "annotate"](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotate/versions/2.7.1). It is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
modelname.all
for eg: Country.all will give you all entries in your table

Answer (score -1):

For viewing the table structure on the rails console only need to run the table name eg If there is a table with name country. only run the 'Country '

2.4.4 :004 > Country
 => Country(id: integer, name: string, percentage: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, is_sync: boolean) 
2.4.4 :005 >